# [rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot_gazebo' not found

Tags: ros, turtlebot-gazebo, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yesterday my turtlebot_gazebo worked just fine.Suddenly today **everytime I open a new terminal**, the following error immediately appears (BEFORE I DO ANYTHING):

```
[rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot_gazebo' not found
[rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot_gazebo' not found
[rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot_navigation' not found
```

When I navigate to /opt/ros/indigo/share , all the turtlebotpackages disappear.
SO I follow the instruction [here](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps ros-indigo-turtlebot-interactions ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi ros-indigo-rocon-remocon ros-indigo-rocon-qt-library ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

and I also install the turtlebot_gazebo

When I install the turtlebot_gazebo, it shows

```
ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

HOWEVER the same problem still appears, and the turtlebot_gazebo package is not in my directory.

PLEASE HELP

-------------------------------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------

I uninstall and reinstall turtlebot..
now turtlebot_gazebo is available, but when i try to launch the example.

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 200, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: kobuki_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

HELP I saw a lot of ppl facing the same problem. I tried the suggested solution, but It doesn't work for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243383/%5Brospack%5D-error:-package-%27turtlebot_gazebo%27-not-found/) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2016-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-08**:
@gvdhoorn @ahendrix @airuno2L please help

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-09**:
it's similar with [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/122021/xacro-problem-invalid-param-tag-cannot-load-command-parameter-robot_description/)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-09**:
Please respect the fact that forum contributors respond on their own time; we're not obligated to help you in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the initial problem.

Uninstall and reinstalling turtlebot solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove turtlebot-*
sudo apt-get intsall ros-indigo-turtlebot
```

For the later problem, I think I'll post it as a new question [HERE](http://answers.ros.org/question/243419/cant-launch-turtlebot_gazebo-example-kobuki_description-not-found/)

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably because of your terminal environment. You need to do this in your new terminal:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-08**:
Nope. it's not the problem.source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash is alr in my bashrc. And source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash is not related w my problem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS has some kind of a problem. Every time you open up your terminal, after entering into your catkin work space, you need to run this `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. So, here is a thing you need to do.

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Let me know what appears after that.

Edit 1: September 09.
OK. Then, I feel that your problem is related to some setting. Sometimes, accidentally something happens and then things stop working in ROS. In this case, what I do is uninstall ROS and install again and check if the error persist. If you want to try, sometimes it is good otherwise wait for someone else to response.

To remove ROS, you need to run this

```
 sudo apt-get remove ros-*
```

Best of luck.

---

Originally posted by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) with karma: 167 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-08**:
As I mentioned in my comment above. I beleive that It has NOTHING to do with that. Cause the error appears even before I tried to do anything. Just immediately after I open a new terminal

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-08**:
Moreover , turtlebot_gazebo is a package that I installed, Not a package that I created on my own.... so it's supposed to go to /opt/ros/indigo/share

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-09**:
Hi Thanks for your suggestion. I reinstalled turtlebot instead of the whole ROS. The error message doesn't appear again in my terminal. However I can not launch thedemo, please see my quest I edited it

**Comment by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on 2018-10-30**:
@alienmon bro can you please post the step that helped you to disappear the error message ? because I have the same problem. I am using ROS kinetic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a lot of debugging, I realised this error was due to sourcing my catkin_ws (I had used the packages directly in catkin_ws rather than installing). Basically, I was getting this error at the start of the terminal because my .bashrc had export of my catkin_ws setup. So, I localised the issue to my catkin_ws. After exploring the filesystem of my catkin_ws, I found some .**sh files** under the directory **catkin_ws/devel/etc/catkin/profile.d/** which belonged to turtlebot. Deleting those specific files solved my problem.

---

Originally posted by [omkar_a_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/58173/omkar_a_k/) with karma: 25 on 2020-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jesusloveyou](https://answers.ros.org/users/58681/jesusloveyou/) on 2021-05-10**:
It solved my problem

**Comment by [elena_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/77667/elena_a/) on 2021-07-13**:
Thank you. This solved my problem as well.